# Identify absolute ability from a wage equation

Tags: labor-economics, wages

Consider a simple model where the wage of a worker $i$ in period $t$ is:

$$w_{it} = \theta_{t} a_{i}$$

where $\theta_{t}$ is the wage rate or efficiency wage per unit of ability, and $a_{i}$ is the workers' ability endowment.

For simplicity let us assume no other factor affects a workers' wage (no experience, education, or any the usual Mincer stuff).

If I run a panel data regression such as (also known as a two-way effects model):

$$ \ln w_{it} = \ln \theta_{t} + \ln a_{i} + \epsilon_{it} $$

then, according to my model, the **estimated effect for the individuals correspond to (the log of) absolute ability**. However, in the literature you always see that predicted unobserved heterogeneity is not ability *per se* but ability together with it's price. This is, there is always a coefficient like in $c\ln a_{i}$ or in $\ln c a_{i}$, and then they move to calculate **relative ability** by just comparing the ratio of predicted heterogeneity for two workers.

I just can't see why it is not possible to identify absolute ability. Where is the missing link in my model?